# filter out a field-value out of a defiined type (list with unknown length)

Tags: types, filter, racket

Image i defined this type:

```
(define-type Example
  [E1(salary number?)]
  [E2(salary number?) (age number?)]
  [E3(salary number?) (name string?)]
  [E4(random number?)])
```

Now i get a list with certain Example-types, like

```
(define e1(E1 4))
(define e2(E2 3000 25))
(define e3(E3 2000 "anton"))
(list e1 e2 e3)
```

and I want to compute the sum of all salaries that are in that list.

My approach would be a filter for the salary field, and then map that. But I have no idea how to filter for a field, I googled so much but I just can't seem to find it, not in the racket guide either. 
So answering this with a code snippet is appreciated, but much more appreciated is where I actually can find how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`type-case`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpabstraction.html?q=define-type#%28form._x._%28%28lib._teachpack%2F2htdp%2Fabstraction..rkt%29._type-case%29%29) can be used to filter the salary of each *type*.

```
(type-case type case-expr (variant (field ...) body-expr) ...)
```

> [type-case] dispatches like a **cond**, matching the result of *case-expr* sequentially against all *variants*. The first successful match triggers the evaluation of the matching *body-expr*, whose value is the result of the entire **type-case** expression.

For example, the following `salary` function extracts the salary from a general `Example` type `e`:

```
(define (salary e)
  (type-case Example e
    [E1 (salary) (E1-salary e)]
    [E2 (salary age) (E2-salary e)]
    [E3 (salary name) (E3-salary e)]
    [E4 (random) 0]))
```

Then, total salary becomes the recursive sum of each list element's salary:

```
(define (sum-salaries lst)
  (if (null? lst) 0 (+ (salary (car lst))
                       (sum-salaries (cdr lst)))))
```

Using the example in question, the sum of salaries becomes:

```
(sum-salaries (list e1 e2 e3))
==> 5004
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where did you find the [type-case] definition?

Comment: It's in the link provided above. See [type-case](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpabstraction.html?q=define-type#%28form._x._%28%28lib._teachpack%2F2htdp%2Fabstraction..rkt%29._type-case%29%29).